# How to return the same template class reusing the template parameters in different order?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have this class:

```
template <class A_Type,int sizeA,int sizeB>
class Matrix {
...
...
...

Matrix transpose()const{
        Matrix<A_Type, sizeB, sizeA> tmp(this->_arrayofarrays[0][0]);
        for (int i=0;i<sizeA;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<sizeB;j++)
                tmp[i][j]=this->_arrayofarrays[j][i];
        return tmp;
    };
}
```

as can see here i just want to get a new Matrix with size B*A

but i get this error:

```
Matrix.h:94:13: error: could not convert ‘tmp’ from ‘Matrix<int, 2, 3>’ to ‘Matrix<int, 3, 2>’
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `Matrix<A_Type, sizeB, sizeA> transpose() { ...}` already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no implicit conversion for `Matrix<int,2,3>` to `Matrix<int,3,2>` indeed. These are different types.

To fix it, explicitly declare the return type with `transpose()`:

```
 Matrix<A_Type, sizeB, sizeA> transpose() {
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
     // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change output type of function `transpose` to `Matrix<A_Type, sizeB, sizeA>`.